# function of arrays of strings in c

Tags: c, arrays

This function stops awsering, and I can't spot the prob, can someone try to find it please?
It is suposed to give me the designed name and number from an array of strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int sameName();
char **getNumber();

char **getNumber (char *n[], char e[],int N){
    int a;
    for(a=0;a<N;a++){
        if (sameName(n[a],e))
        {
            return n[a];
        }
    }
    return "Not found!";
}

int sameName(char n[], char e[]){
    int a;
    for(a=0;e[a]!='\0';a++){
        if (n[a]!=e[a])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main (){
    char numbers [5] [100] ={{"Ash 031"},{"Bomberman 021"},{"Rango 120"},{"Gigo Senhas 017"},{"Marcoreano 135"}};
    char name [100];
    char a [100];
    scanf("%s",&a);
    strcpy(name,getNumber (numbers,a,5));
    printf("%s\n",name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually debugged it?

Comment: with the gdb debugger? It gives em a sgementation fault on sameName

Comment: The prototype `int sameName();` tells the compiler *nothing* about the function arguments, so it is useless as a forward reference.

Comment: should I just put it in a comment or erase it?

Comment: No, it needs the correct prototype: that is what it is for. `sameName` is called by `getNumber`, which precedes `sameName` implementation. So the dead prototype does not tell the compiler what the arguments should be.

Comment: Is sameName just checking if two strings are the name? Use [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) instead. Also, this code is loaded with compiler warnings. Fix them first.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to be doing. Could you edit it with sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Well, It asks what name I choose (Imagine I type "Ash") and it gves me the name string of the name (In this case it would print "Ash 031")

Comment: It's not the same, but rather the prefix of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spicify the size of your two-dimension array when you pass it to your `getNumber` function. See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html for details.

And for `scanf` you only need to pass `a` since it is a string.

Taking these plus fixing your prototypes as mentioned in the comment above, that gives :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int sameName(char n[], char e[]);
char *getNumber (char n[][100], char e[],int N);

char *getNumber (char n[][100], char e[],int N){
    int a;
    for(a=0;a<N;a++){
        if (sameName(n[a],e))
        {
            return n[a];
        }
    }
    return "Not found!";
}

int sameName(char n[], char e[]){
    int a;
    for(a=0;e[a]!='\0';a++){
        if (n[a]!=e[a])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

 int main (){
    char numbers [5] [100] ={{"Ash 031"},{"Bomberman 021"},{"Rango 120"},{"Gigo Senhas 017"},{"Marcoreano 135"}};
    char name [100];
    char a [100];
    scanf("%s",a);

    strcpy(name,getNumber (numbers,a,5));
    printf("%s\n",name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, might I suggest returning (and checking for) NULL rather than "Not found!", which is a perfectly normal string.